# JAXB - @XMLTransient fields disappear when returned to UI

Tags: java, jackson, jaxb, jax-rs

My application uses several POJOs in the backend to marshall data from the backend to the UI.  The data comes from the DB as a string, it gets mapped using Jackson into our POJOs, and then we return the object in the API call using `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`.  When migrating the app to JBoss 7 EAP, we noticed that any field marked with `@XmlTransient` was not getting marshalled into JSON when it was returned to the UI.  The POJO object had all the fields populated, but on the UI end they would not show up in the JSON string at all.  Example:

```
//class POJO
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class FetchDataVO {
  @XmlTransient
  private String Id;

  private String name;

  @XmlTransient
  private String domain;
}
```

And our API response would look like:

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApiOperation(value = "getUserById", nickname = "getUserById")
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = FetchDataVO.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Failure")})

public @ResponseBody
    @Valid fetchDataVO getUserById(
            @PathParam("id") String id){


    FetchDataVO fetchVO = callDataBase.getUserById(id);

    //All the data will be present here, everything is correct so far
    log.info("fetchVO contents - " + fetchVO.printDetails());

    return fetchVO;
}
```

Our backend code would print out the POJO with all the fields correct.  However, when we call it in our UI, we see the response as:

```
{"name":null}
```

The other fields don't even show up.  Like I mentioned, this only happened after migrating to version 3.0+ of jackson due to the JBoss upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Jackson is capable of recognizing JAXB annotations to configure the serialization/deserialization.

Unfortunately, at some point Wildfly/JBoss JAX-RS implementation, RestEasy, enabled this feature by default. So, if your bean is annotated with `@XmlRootElement`, Jackson will honour `@XmlTransient` annotations and hence ignore the field.

As a workaround to disable it, you can use a JAX-RS `ContextResolver` to configure the Jackson `ObjectMapper` without this feature.

To get a plain `ObjectMapper` just add something like this on your REST module:

```
@Provider
public class JacksonObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public JacksonObjectMapperContextResolver() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // additional configuration here if needed
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return mapper;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you try it?